# smtp relay shows temporary lookup failure

Tags: smtp

We deploy a new smtp relay server in ubuntu. When send test email from the root the mail flows properly. But when we use it as relay server it shows "temporary lookup failure"

Where should we need to config in the postfix. Need some help. Here is our postfixs main.cf file

```
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
mydomain = efftelsolutions.net
myhostname = netexsmtp.efftelsolutions.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, smtp.solutions.net, localhost.solutions.net, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 88.82.175.33/27 88.82.175.225 88.82.175.65/27
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Answer (score 1):

you have error in `mynetworks` section, you need to specify correct network addresses (beginig of the range, not gateway address)

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 88.82.175.32/27 88.82.175.225 88.82.175.64/27
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Corrected the network address and it works.